# How to pass current item field value to the url of each item of a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, view, url

I have a list of items

[image: list]

And the url of each item is something like this :
site/layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=xxx...

I am not sure what PageType and ListId are for, but I would like to be able to customize this url and add the parameter ID Name to it
For example for the first item: site/layouts/15/listform.aspx?PageType=4&ListId=xxx...&**IdName=01**

Do you think it is possible ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Looks like a solution is to use a calculated column type.

Indeed in the library setting of the list I can create a column type Calculated and then in the formula I use this :
     ="https://serversite/sites/siteName/Lists/listName/item/DispForm.aspx?   ID="&ID&"&IdName="&IdName&"'>"&Title&""

By doing so it would create an hyperlink with the correct parameter.